# How to remove implicit declaration in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to remove the implicit declaration error I have:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ 1: { length: number; }; 2: { length: number; }; 3: { length: number; }; 4: { length: number; }; }'

Do I declare and interface for a specific function? This error occurs whenever accessing an index of the `steps` constant.

```
interface Step {
  length: number
}

interface Steps {
  [index: number]: Step
}

const min_x = 0
const max_x = 1
const steps = {
  1: { length: 1 },
  2: { length: 1 },
  3: { length: 1 },
  4: { length: 1 }
}
const sum = Object.keys( steps ).reduce( ( sum, key ): number => sum + parseFloat( steps[key].length || 0 ), 0 )
let start = min_x
Object.keys( steps ).forEach( ( key: any ) => {
  steps[ key ][`start`] = start;
  steps[ key ][`stop`] = start + ( steps[ key ].length / sum );
  start = start + ( steps[ key ].length / sum );
} )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you wokring fine in ts playground.

interface Step {
length: number
start?: number
stop?: number
}

```
interface Steps {
    [index: number]: Step
}

const min_x = 0
const max_x = 1
const steps: Steps = {
    1: { length: 1 }
}

const sum = Object.keys(steps).reduce((sum, key): number => sum + steps[+key].length, 0)
let start = min_x
Object.keys(steps).forEach((key: any) => {
    steps[key][`start`] = start;
    steps[key][`stop`] = start + (steps[key].length / sum);
    start = start + (steps[key].length / sum);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet, and you can refer to code I've changed.

```
interface Step {
  length: number,
  start?: number,
  stop?: number
}

interface Steps {
  [index: string]: Step // index type is string or number, string would be better.
}

const min_x = 0
const max_x = 1
const steps: Steps = {
  1: { length: 1 },
  2: { length: 1 },
  3: { length: 1 },
  4: { length: 1 }
}

// parseFloat only accepts type of string
const sum = Object.keys( steps ).reduce( ( sum, key ): number => sum + parseFloat( String(steps[key].length || 0) ), 0 )
let start = min_x
Object.keys( steps ).forEach( ( key ) => {
  steps[ key ][`start`] = start;
  steps[ key ][`stop`] = start + ( steps[ key ].length / sum );
  start = start + ( steps[ key ].length / sum );
} )
```